# Prevent VBA Flickering Of Charts In Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that contains 2 sheets. A VBA code will load a CSV file into the 1st sheet. The VBA code will then plot data from the 1st sheet into charts in the 2nd sheet. This VBA code runs every 5 seconds and causes the charts to flicker.

Anyone has any suggestions to prevent the flickering? I have tried

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and it does not help.

Comment: Adding that code you run in every 5 seconds can be helpful ;).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have noticed that refreshing the data connection to the csv file would cause the charts to flicker. I resolved this problem by removing the data connection and parsing the csv file manually and setting the data into the charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the worksheet that has the charts just before you are about to load the CSV data, and then unhide at the end of the second macro.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the macro outside of the VBA editor?
Even if you have set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, this will be ignored if stepping through the code or running from the editor (I believe!)